# Pad data with zeros on the server-side

Tags: php, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables. And I have this code working properly:

```
$res = $this->connection->prepare("....");

$res->bindParam(1,$id);
$res->execute();
$result = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$data = array(
   'data'=>$result
);

return json_encode($data);
```

And this how the result looks like.

> {"data":[{"id":"10","time_in":"2015-07-06 07:30:00","time_out":"2015-07-06 10:26:11"
>   ,"attended":"yes"},{"id":"9","time_in":"2015-07-06 08:00:00","time_out":"2015-07-06
>    11:46:36","attended":"yes"}]}

But I want my `id` to be zero padded as shown below.

> {"data":[{"id":"00010","time_in":"2015-07-06 07:30:00","time_out":"2015-07-06 10:26:11"
>   ,"attended":"yes"},{"id":"00009","time_in":"2015-07-06 08:00:00","time_out":"2015-07-06
>    11:46:36","attended":"yes"}]}

How can I achieve this
so that I can output the result like this and I can display it in the data table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MySQL**

In MySQL you can use [LPAD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad).

For example, to pad field `id` with zeros to 5 characters, use the statement below.

```
SELECT LPAD(id,5,'0') AS id FROM table;
```

**PostgreSQL**

In PostgreSQL you can use [LPAD()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html). If `id` is integer, it would need to be type-casted to string.

For example, to pad field `id` with zeros to 5 characters, use the statement below.

```
SELECT LPAD(id::text,5,'0') AS id FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the clean SQL method, but you have the `PHP` tags; so I could not resist.

```
$res = $this->connection->prepare("....");

$res->bindParam(1, $id);
$res->execute();
$result = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $row):
    $row['id'] = sprintf('%05d', $row['id']);
endforeach;

$data = array(
    'data' => $result
);

return json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I tried @Manu Varghese, but i got error on it "REPLICATE function" is not exists.

Comment: I'm not a SQL wizard, so I don't know if it works. I would recommend if it's something you always will be applying and it can be done reasonably with SQL, do it with SQL.

Comment: I decoded your JSON string for my own convenience, which causes it to be an object; but you are using `FETCH_ASSOC`, which is an array, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Strange, check if `$row['id']` really exists and is being overwritten, or check if `sprintf('%05d', 10);` works on your PHP installation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this SQL statement, it will solve your problem:

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0',5-LEN(RTRIM(Id))) + RTRIM(Id) .......
```

Comment: Is replicate can be use in mysql ?

Comment: This appears to be MS SQL Server specific. MySQL has the `LPAD` function.